# Can vertical window be installed horizontally?

Tags: windows

I have a double-paned window that is not designed to open. It is 7' x 1'. The weep holes are in the 1' end. Can this window be installed horizontally?

Answer (score 4):

NO, you cannot install a window in the wrong orientation.

Glass is “set” in window frames using “setting blocks”. These blocks are made for the weight of the glass to rest on. They are sized and distributed according to the weight of the glass.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly can, but you almost certainly shouldn't.  The weep holes are where they are because they're designed to ensure that any water collecting in the window frame area drain away again.  If you turn the window to the incorrect orientation those holes can no longer do their job.

Comment: Assuming that it'll be exposed to rain. If it's up under a wide overhang or whatever it may not be a concern.

Comment: Maybe - but you can still get driving rain.  Using the product in a manner other than that for which it was intended is never something I can recommend.